# Is it safe to store rechargeable lithium ion batteries and SD memory in a zip lock bag?

Tags: battery, sdcard, storage

My camera uses a rechargeable lithium ion battery and an SD memory card.  When I'm out shooting and at home, I normally keep an extra of each in a zip lock type of plastic storage bag (the card is first put into the plastic holder that it came with).  Is this a safe way to store them?  If not, is there a better way to avoid any problems?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should a DSLR camera, lens, and battery be stored?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/how-should-a-dslr-camera-lens-and-battery-be-stored)

Comment: Different issue-I noticed this question before posting mine.

Comment: I sure hope so! That's how I carry around my spare batteries and cards. But before your question I never even wondered if it's safe. I have no idea. I've never had a problem. Why wouldn't it be safe?

Comment: @user4894 My initial thought was the possibility of static electricity associated with the plastic possibly having some impact on the card. The battery part of the question evolved.

Answer (score 5):

SD cards are very safe when stored in their original plastic container at room temperature in a dry place. The same is generally true of Lithium Ion batteries. Protecting the metal contacts on the SD card and battery will prevent the majority of damage to either device, either through corrosion, physical damage, or electrical short. Storing the memory card (in its plastic case) and battery in separate plastic bags should protect from most problems.

Optimally the battery should be stored at about 60 degrees F and roughly 50 percent charge. The exact charge can be difficult to determine, and the charge percentage needed increases with temperature, but in practical use this is really only a concern for long-term storage.

Comment: This: The only risks would be from either a battery-to-card short, or a battery short (which most Lithium Ion packs are very well protected against) causing a catastrophic event damaging the card.

Answer (score -5):

Personalĺy, I would never store or carry ANY camera cards and ANY batteries together. Card info storage operates electronically and batteries can have a strong (albeit local) magnetic field. To put one's faith in the card, and any files saved on it, being unaffected by being in close proximity to batteries isn't something I'd recommend.

Comment: _batteries can have a strong (albeit local) magnetic field._ Not really. If they're not supplying current, then there is basically zero magnetic field. And if they are supplying current, it is still a rather weak field. And SD cards are fairly immune to interference from magnetic fields. You can tape an SD card to a strong neodymium magnet for a day, and not experience any data integrity problems.

Comment: Also, some cameras have the (in use!!) battery and card very close together, eg the Sony A6000 and NEX-7.

Comment: Exception to magnetic fields not mattering at all: MicroDrive type CF cards. These could indeed take damage from the neodymium magnet (not from an idle battery though!).

Comment: Electrical engineer who's day job is building flash memory devices here -- This is false.  Unlike HDDs and other magnetic storage, flash memory is basically immune to magnetic fields, and batteries don't create much of a magnetic field anyway.